# How do I securely identify a remote device in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, embedded, security

Is there a safe way, to identify a device which might be behind a Router (so the IP is not unique) in PHP?

Background: I have several embedded devices (self programmed & adaptable) which contact a webserver (php+mysql) with status updates. These updates are then - if the source is confirmed - saved to the database.

- As I understand it `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` usually can be trusted (except some IIS configuration where it may - under special circumstances - wrongfully return 127.0.0.1; but different story)
- Anyhow since I use SSL, the IP address really should not be a problem, because there a handshake is required and if the IP is faked or simply wrong, the connection should not be established
- For now I require IP addresses to be whitelisted by admin, for an status update to be acceppted
- The device additionally sends the MAC address via `$_POST` to identify the different modules with identical IP address (I know this can very easily be forged, and right now will be trusted if the IP address is trusted)

---

So first of all I am not sure if the IP address in itself is enough for it to be safe from attacks from the outside

Secondly if the device is behind a router, it will have the same IP address as every PC/device on that network. So about anyone there could forge a status update with a fake MAC address (simply as post variable), and since the IP address is whitelisted it will be trusted

**So is there any way of confirming the identity of a device, or do you know a better way of doing this?**

Aside: *Going the other way, and have the webserver poll the different devices might be an option, but since there might be many (> 2000) devices of which we need the very last status (change) I thought it to be inefficient.*

Comment: Your question would probably be a better fit at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do that! Thank you also for the hint to use a signed certificate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP addresses can be spoofed, MAC addresses can be forged, so theses methods are not sufficient. The general approach is to assign a key to each client device (possibly the same key to all devices, even if this probably a bad idea). The "key" can be anything from a predefined string (weak, think username/password) to a signed certificate (strong, think SSL).

Both can be implemented either at the application level (by PHP) or at server level. If your application runs on Apache `httpd` server, I would rather recommend using its built-in features as it supports [both](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_authz_core.html) [approaches](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol).